# Overlay driver not being applied when creating docker swarm network

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, docker-network

I'm working with docker swarm and trying to create a network with the `overlay` driver.

**Whenever I create the network, the driver is not attached.**

1. If I try and attach a service to the network, the process just hangs infinitely.
2. If I create a service *without* attaching it to the network, it works right away.

```
pi@node3:~ $ docker network ls
NETWORK ID     NAME              DRIVER    SCOPE
a1cc2e1f4f2b   bridge            bridge    local
83597f713bcf   docker_gwbridge   bridge    local
277f1166485e   host              host      local
fs2vvjeuejxc   ingress           overlay   swarm
5d0ce08c744c   none              null      local

pi@node3:~ $ docker network create --driver overlay test
4bfkahhkhrblod2t79yd83vws

pi@node3:~ $ docker network ls
NETWORK ID     NAME              DRIVER    SCOPE
a1cc2e1f4f2b   bridge            bridge    local
83597f713bcf   docker_gwbridge   bridge    local
277f1166485e   host              host      local
fs2vvjeuejxc   ingress           overlay   swarm
5d0ce08c744c   none              null      local
4bfkahhkhrbl   test                        swarm
```

I can't figure out why it's not adding the driver. I have a suspicion it has something to do with the ingress network settings, but I'm stuck as for troubleshooting here.

#### Relevant Info

Swarm:

```
pi@node3:~ $ docker node ls
ID                            HOSTNAME   STATUS    AVAILABILITY   MANAGER STATUS   ENGINE VERSION
ygcte2diochpbgu7bqtw41k70     node1      Ready     Active                          20.10.7
xbllxgfa35937rmvdi8mi8dlb     node2      Ready     Active                          20.10.7
tvw4b53w6g3qv2k3919dg3a81 *   node3      Ready     Active         Leader           20.10.7
```

Manager node:

```
pi@node3:~ $ docker node inspect node3
[
    {
        "ID": "tvw4b53w6g3qv2k3919dg3a81",
        "Version": {
            "Index": 165
        },
        "CreatedAt": "2021-07-10T16:41:23.043334654Z",
        "UpdatedAt": "2021-07-11T00:27:25.807737662Z",
        "Spec": {
            "Labels": {},
            "Role": "manager",
            "Availability": "active"
        },
        "Description": {
            "Hostname": "node3",
            "Platform": {
                "Architecture": "armv7l",
                "OS": "linux"
            },
            "Resources": {
                "NanoCPUs": 4000000000,
                "MemoryBytes": 969105408
            },
            "Engine": {
                "EngineVersion": "20.10.7",
                "Plugins": [
                    {
                        "Type": "Log",
                        "Name": "awslogs"
                    },
                    {
                        "Type": "Log",
                        "Name": "fluentd"
                    },
                    {
                        "Type": "Log",
                        "Name": "gcplogs"
                    },
                    {
                        "Type": "Log",
                        "Name": "gelf"
                    },
                    {
                        "Type": "Log",
                        "Name": "journald"
                    },
                    {
                        "Type": "Log",
                        "Name": "json-file"
                    },
                    {
                        "Type": "Log",
                        "Name": "local"
                    },
                    {
                        "Type": "Log",
                        "Name": "logentries"
                    },
                    {
                        "Type": "Log",
                        "Name": "splunk"
                    },
                    {
                        "Type": "Log",
                        "Name": "syslog"
                    },
                    {
                        "Type": "Network",
                        "Name": "bridge"
                    },
                    {
                        "Type": "Network",
                        "Name": "host"
                    },
                    {
                        "Type": "Network",
                        "Name": "ipvlan"
                    },
                    {
                        "Type": "Network",
                        "Name": "macvlan"
                    },
                    {
                        "Type": "Network",
                        "Name": "null"
                    },
                    {
                        "Type": "Network",
                        "Name": "overlay"
                    },
                    {
                        "Type": "Volume",
                        "Name": "local"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "TLSInfo": {
                "TrustRoot": "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\nMIIBajCCARCgAwIBAgIUFIx3NAw+jgaasNXCoi+QP4GxaOQwCgYIKoZIzj0EAwIw\nEzERMA8GA1UEAxMIc3dhcm0tY2EwHhcNMjEwNzEwMTYyMjAwWhcNNDEwNzA1MTYy\nMjAwWjATMREwDwYDVQQDEwhzd2FybS1jYTBZMBMGByqGSM49AgEGCCqGSM49AwEH\nA0IABKyunnrZtfkOO+Cc/MX/qbyJjG12ee8es0IHB1HXF2MhqSfYOeUuBlTvuHuB\nxl8s8eQ4IMfjP0w5LYJNqypZp0KjQjBAMA4GA1UdDwEB/wQEAwIBBjAPBgNVHRMB\nAf8EBTADAQH/MB0GA1UdDgQWBBRq6yBEIFv03tQqBkohCh4A+mIZdTAKBggqhkjO\nPQQDAgNIADBFAiA5kKgC2WxcOMyfrmFr8fU6w1Mo1mq5GMKA4owTB7pcEQIhALZi\n9AH0vVyR+7NmmR7LfPO65CIJ9UVuPZBXRZ6pcmzX\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n",
                "CertIssuerSubject": "MBMxETAPBgNVBAMTCHN3YXJtLWNh",
                "CertIssuerPublicKey": "MFkwEwYHKoZIzj0CAQYIKoZIzj0DAQcDQgAErK6eetm1+Q474Jz8xf+pvImMbXZ57x6zQgcHUdcXYyGpJ9g55S4GVO+4e4HGXyzx5Dggx+M/TDktgk2rKlmnQg=="
            }
        },
        "Status": {
            "State": "ready",
            "Addr": "0.0.0.0"
        },
        "ManagerStatus": {
            "Leader": true,
            "Reachability": "reachable",
            "Addr": "10.0.0.93:2377"
        }
    }
```

Ingress network:

```
pi@node3:~ $ docker network inspect ingress
[
    {
        "Name": "ingress",
        "Id": "fs2vvjeuejxcjxqivenb76kgj",
        "Created": "2021-07-10T17:24:14.228552858-07:00",
        "Scope": "swarm",
        "Driver": "overlay",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": null,
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "10.10.0.0/24",
                    "Gateway": "10.10.0.1"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Attachable": false,
        "Ingress": true,
        "ConfigFrom": {
            "Network": ""
        },
        "ConfigOnly": false,
        "Containers": {
            "ingress-sbox": {
                "Name": "ingress-endpoint",
                "EndpointID": "34003d042d395b90328ed90c8133505a6bec6df90065c5b47b47ee3853545c91",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:0a:0a:00:02",
                "IPv4Address": "10.10.0.2/24",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            }
        },
        "Options": {
            "com.docker.network.driver.overlay.vxlanid_list": "4096"
        },
        "Labels": {},
        "Peers": [
            {
                "Name": "e2f4d4e6ba20",
                "IP": "10.0.0.93"
            },
            {
                "Name": "de3d98ce0f8d",
                "IP": "10.0.0.25"
            },
            {
                "Name": "b61722e30756",
                "IP": "10.0.0.12"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Docker version:

```
pi@node3:~ $ docker --version
Docker version 20.10.7, build f0df350
```

Docker info:

```
pi@node3:~ $ docker info
Client:
 Context:    default
 Debug Mode: false
 Plugins:
  app: Docker App (Docker Inc., v0.9.1-beta3)
  buildx: Build with BuildKit (Docker Inc., v0.5.1-docker)

Server:
 Containers: 0
  Running: 0
  Paused: 0
  Stopped: 0
 Images: 5
 Server Version: 20.10.7
 Storage Driver: overlay2
  Backing Filesystem: extfs
  Supports d_type: true
  Native Overlay Diff: true
  userxattr: false
 Logging Driver: json-file
 Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
 Cgroup Version: 1
 Plugins:
  Volume: local
  Network: bridge host ipvlan macvlan null overlay
  Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file local logentries splunk syslog
 Swarm: active
  NodeID: tvw4b53w6g3qv2k3919dg3a81
  Is Manager: true
  ClusterID: 4vf16jdlegf3ctys5k6wumcfc
  Managers: 1
  Nodes: 3
  Default Address Pool: 10.10.0.0/24  
  SubnetSize: 24
  Data Path Port: 4789
  Orchestration:
   Task History Retention Limit: 5
  Raft:
   Snapshot Interval: 10000
   Number of Old Snapshots to Retain: 0
   Heartbeat Tick: 1
   Election Tick: 10
  Dispatcher:
   Heartbeat Period: 5 seconds
  CA Configuration:
   Expiry Duration: 3 months
   Force Rotate: 0
  Autolock Managers: false
  Root Rotation In Progress: false
  Node Address: 10.0.0.93
  Manager Addresses:
   10.0.0.93:2377
 Runtimes: io.containerd.runc.v2 io.containerd.runtime.v1.linux runc
 Default Runtime: runc
 Init Binary: docker-init
 containerd version: d71fcd7d8303cbf684402823e425e9dd2e99285d
 runc version: b9ee9c6314599f1b4a7f497e1f1f856fe433d3b7
 init version: de40ad0
 Security Options:
  seccomp
   Profile: default
 Kernel Version: 5.10.17-v7+
 Operating System: Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)
 OSType: linux
 Architecture: armv7l
 CPUs: 4
 Total Memory: 924.2MiB
 Name: node3
 ID: A67O:SIT4:QOMH:SILY:WHAY:KSGQ:VWMF:QVEJ:VCOZ:KW32:PZRV:ZD4B
 Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
 Debug Mode: false
 Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
 Labels:
 Experimental: false
 Insecure Registries:
  127.0.0.0/8
 Live Restore Enabled: false

WARNING: No memory limit support
WARNING: No swap limit support
WARNING: No kernel memory TCP limit support
WARNING: No oom kill disable support
WARNING: No blkio throttle.read_bps_device support
WARNING: No blkio throttle.write_bps_device support
WARNING: No blkio throttle.read_iops_device support
WARNING: No blkio throttle.write_iops_device support
```

#### What I've tried:

1. Removing all the nodes and creating a new swarm
2. Removing the ingress network and creating a new one following [the instructions here](https://docs.docker.com/network/overlay/#customize-the-default-ingress-network)
3. Tried to go through the walkthrough [here](https://docs.docker.com/network/network-tutorial-overlay/#walkthrough) but can't get past Create the Services 2.
4. Rebooted all the nodes

Any advice or pointing in the right direction would be much appreciated! I've been stuck here for 48 hours.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Solved!

The issue ended up being:

1. The nodes were all on `10.0.0.x`
2. I set the `--default-addr-pool 10.10.0.0/24` when initializing the swarm

Any network I tried to create using the `--driver overlay` would end up without any subnet or gateway information.

### How I resolved the issue:

I was able to solve it using the `--subnet` flag when creating a custom network.

```
pi@node3:~ $ docker network create --driver overlay --subnet 10.10.10.0/24 test
```

```
pi@node3:~ $ docker network ls
NETWORK ID     NAME              DRIVER    SCOPE
55ab64773261   bridge            bridge    local
ce1a0f497e9d   docker_gwbridge   bridge    local
7c85cac72cf8   host              host      local
o7iew29j70nl   ingress           overlay   swarm
ca5fc5682911   none              null      local
plezwc8zahpl   test              overlay   swarm
```

```
pi@node3:~ $ docker network inspect test
[
    {
        "Name": "test",
        "Id": "plezwc8zahpl9gs8hbv64bbo3",
        "Created": "2021-07-16T17:30:28.773110478Z",
        "Scope": "swarm",
        "Driver": "overlay",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": null,
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "10.10.10.0/24",
                    "Gateway": "10.10.10.1"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Attachable": false,
        "Ingress": false,
        "ConfigFrom": {
            "Network": ""
        },
        "ConfigOnly": false,
        "Containers": null,
        "Options": {
            "com.docker.network.driver.overlay.vxlanid_list": "4097"
        },
        "Labels": null
    }
]
```